# ng-list equivalent in Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular

Having a difficulty finding documentation on this, but in Angular 1 you could do:

```html
<textarea ng-model="name" ng-list=","></textarea>
```

Then on input, if you were to enter "Hello, world!" `name` would be an array of `["Hello", "world!"]`.

My goal is to use `ng-list` with the HTML entity `&#10;` for breaking a `textarea` by line into an array. See [example from docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngList#example-splitting-on-newline).

Is there an equivalent of this in Angular 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could not find native solution, but you can use `(ngModelChange)` and then get the parsed value like this:

```
  parseTextArea() {
     this.textareaParsed = this.textarea.split("\n");
  }
```

and in your template:

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="textarea" (ngModelChange)="parseTextArea()"></textarea>
```

See this plunker: [textarea example](https://plnkr.co/edit/5NskHGBBzOwA06ZYBzKt?p=preview) (*in Chrome, IE has some issues with config.js*...)

Comment: I thought this might be the way to go, I'll leave the question open for a while to see if anything else comes in.

Comment: Has anyone found a better solution yet?