# Angular 2 equivalent to ngList

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-directives

In Angular 1, you could automatically convert a delimited input to an array in the model using the `ngList` directive, as such:

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('listExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ['john','jane','joe'];
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="listExample" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <label>List: <input name="namesInput" ng-model="names" ng-list=", "></label>
  <br/>
  <tt>names = {{names}}</tt>
</div>
```

Is there any built in feature in Angular 2 to accomplish the same? I have searched the Angular 2 documentation and was unable to find any such directive.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40906101/ng-list-equivalent-in-angular-2