# ng-list equivalent in Angular?

Tags: angular

I want to use ng-list with the HTML entity 
 for breaking a textarea by line into an array.

Is there an equivalent of this in Angular?

In AngularJS you could do:

```
<textarea ng-model="name" ng-list=","></textarea>
```

Then on input, if you were to enter "Hello, world!" name would be an array of `["Hello", "world!"]`.

Please share working solution if possible.

I have already checked : [ng-list equivalent in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40906101/9050638)

but this is not providing me a good solution.

Comment: _but this is not providing me a good solution._ mind explaining why? it does **exactly** what you need, you just need to change `\n` with `,`.

Comment: My model data is not changing with this solution.

Comment: can you please provide the code you're using?

Comment: If you want it neater. Just create a custom pipe `

Comment: @briosheje . ngModelChange event occur each time when I change the text in textarea. This is not required behaviour . I need to populate array in textarea with bullets in each line separated with each element of array. if ("p1","p2") is received from database then I need to populate textarea with two line starting with bullet and then p1 and p2.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pmbc7q .

Comment: @Nancy the directive you provided works beautifully. What's wrong with that?

Comment: change html as <textarea rows="10" cols="40" [(ngModel)]="stringArray" appDotTextBox [(stringArray)]="stringArray"></textarea> you will see that the data in textarea changed.

Comment: @Nancy it's because you just shouldn't use ngModel in that case. Is there any reason you are using it? you can use `stringArrayChange` to be alerted when the textarea is changed.

Comment: I am new to angular...if you can suggest some working example then please do. I have explained my requirement in above comment. Please refer that. I don’t know stringArrayChange to use. I am glad you are trying to help.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to split the string into an array you can use JavaScript, no angular needed.

```js
var test = "Hello, world!"
var arrTest = test.split(',')
console.log(arrTest)
```